# Calculating monetary base from given data

Tags: monetary-policy, data-request

I need to some data for Pakistan's monetary base. Searching through the website of State Bank of Pakistan (SBP), I found the following pdf on [Monetary Statistics](http://www.sbp.org.pk/departments/stats/PakEconomy_HandBook/Chap-4.1.pdf).

I wanted to ask that can I calculate monetary base from the given values.

Following is a list of values given in pdf in case pdf is not opening for you.

1. Currency in Circulation
2. Other Deposits with SBP
3. Currency in Tills of Scheduled Banks
4. Banks' Deposits with SBP

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into monetary base definition:

> Monetary base is the total amount of a currency that is either circulated in the hands of the public or in the commercial bank deposits held in the central bank's reserves.

So this means that M0 is actually the monetary base. So I really don't have to calculate anything.